# Remove punctuation from column names of a data frame imported from a CSV - R

Tags: r, csv

I've read a CSV in R which just contain column names. There's space in some column names, however when this is imported the space is replaced by a point.

The code is the following:

```
opr <- read.csv("~/opr.csv")
```

Now, If we see the names of the data frame there's no space between words.

```
names(opr)
 [1] "ALUMNO"                 "CICLO"                 
 [3] "TIPO.EX"                "NIVEL"                 
 [5] "Aritmetica.pregunta.1"  "Aritmetica.pregunta.2" 
 [7] "Aritmetica.pregunta.3"  "Aritmetica.pregunta.4"
```

I would like to know how to replace the points by space as in the csv.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want `gsub`.  This should do it.

```
names(opr) <- gsub("[.]", " ", names(opr))
```

Or for less copying, you can also use `attr<-` instead of `names<-`

```
attr(opr, "names") <- gsub("[.]", " ", names(opr))
```

Comment: I' really didn`t know about "gsub function" . Thanks!

Comment: @RichardScriven: Those periods _are_ the result of `make.names`. My preference is for underscores, so I change all the periods to "_". I think the questioner will have even more difficulty down the road if he makes 'check.names' FALSE. Prediction: He'll and up with spaces and dollar signs and then won't be able to understand the errors.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps easiest of all, just tell `read.csv` that the column names are fine how they are:

```
opr <- read.csv("~/opr.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: see @BondedDust's comment below Richard Scriven's answer, which is worth taking into account ...

Comment: @BenBolker I don't disagree, but the OP is specifically asking for spaces in his column names. I'd think of using `check.names = F` like directly calling `.Internal(mean(x))`: not good as a general practice, but if used sparingly in a controlled environment it can turn out okay.

Answer (score 1):

```
names(opr)<-sapply(names(opr), function(name) paste(unlist(strsplit(name, ".", fixed=TRUE)), collapse = " "))
```

Comment: I have to get used to "apply functions". I' m learning to clean data. Thanks!